# Columns don’t exist

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, identifier

What I am doing is querying the database with this query:

```
Select * From nutrition Where ID=2
```

It says "Column name ID doesn't exist", when it is an auto increment column in the database.

Then I tried something different.

```
Select * From nutrition Where desc="s"
```

It said "Column name "s" doesn't exist".

Why is it picking up "s" and not desc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the remaining first question, my educated guess would be you double quoted the column name `"ID"` . Either when creating the table or when querying. `"ID"` is not the same as `ID` or `id` or `"id"`, since unquoted identifiers are cast to lower case in Postgres.

[Read the chapter "Identifiers and Key Words" in the manual to understand.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, `"s"` is not a string; identifiers are enclosed in `"` in SQL. Use single quotes. (And avoid `desc`, as it’s a keyword.)

```
SELECT * FROM nutrition WHERE "desc" = 's'
```

As for your first query… `ID` really doesn’t exist. Did you get the casing right?